# How to change the User Agent string in Edge or Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, chromium

How can I change the User Agent string in either Edge or Chrome on Android?

I found old tutorials suggesting either going to `about:debug` or `about:useragent` but neither of these seem to work anymore.

Comment: It used to be possible on Chrome if your device is rooted //Last I tried it didn't work on rooted devices too// Try other browsers like Dolphin etc which claim to support

Comment: I don't know which tutorials you read, but Chrome internal urls don't start with about, but only with chrome. It is Firefox which starts with about. Plus, if chrome flags don't support it, there is nothing you can do, except when using remote debugging. A reasonable solution is to use Chrome based Kiwi browser. Kiwi browser supports extensions made for Chrome desktop.